# Audio does not play unless I restart pulseaudio or switch device

Tags: fedora, pulseaudio

I was using/trying `paprefs` to stream audio to a remote device, however, after that, my system stops playing audio unless I go into settings and switch device to another and back (or restart `pulseaudio` with `-k` option in the terminal). This happens whenever no sound is played for a couple of seconds.

What I have tried:

- Remove `paprefs`.
- Remove `~/.config/pulse` (and reboot).
- Set the default sink to my desired output device.

It prevents playing any video (i.e. YouTube) too until it can use audio output like described above, and then, when the video stops I have to repeat with the switch or restart `pulseaudio`.

My System:

- Fedora 36
- GNome 42.4
- Pulseaudio 15.0
- Kernel 5.19.16-200
- Onboard Sounddevice (ASUS X99-A mainboard)

I think it is not device related because I have a USB-Headset and there is the issue same.

Comment: I do not know the situation of Fedora 36 (and next); but I know the case of Debian, in Debian 12 (last version) the default is PipeWire instead Pulseaudio, so people that upgrade directly from Debian 11 to Debian 12 have the exactly same problem you have. So, our solution is remove Pulseaudio and configure PipeWire (there is a transition). Probably in Fedora, you can find a similiar situation and solution.

Answer (score 0):

[sinkmanu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/202010/sinkmanu) [said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735756/audio-not-play-unless-restart-pulseaudio-or-switch-device#comment1433669_735756):

> ...our solution is remove Pulseaudio and configure PipeWire (there is a transition). Probably in Fedora, you can find a similiar situation and solution.

Based on that, on Fedora 39 KDE spin, I followed the steps mentioned in [r/Fefdora: Remove PulseAudio from F34?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/ogdi5f/remove_pulseaudio_from_f34/) by [gjack905](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/ogdi5f/comment/h4im18e/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button):

> 1. Run `sudo dnf swap pulseaudio pipewire-pulseaudio --allowerasing` to upgrade properly
> 2. Run `sudo dnf reinstall pipewire pipewire-pulseaudio`, per Fedora's documentation, to blow away any config file weirdness there may (or may not) have been left over. I didn't have Pipewire installed before the upgrade, but whatever, why not, as a preventative measure.
> 3. Run `systemctl --user stop pulseaudio` to stop the old PulseAudio service that was still running. Remember the `--user` flag, that confused me for a bit in the beginning, wondering why nothing was showing up. (Also, don't use sudo here, it needs to run as you.)
> 4. Run `systemctl --user daemon-reload` because it told me to after Step 3.
> 5. Run `systemctl --user restart pipewire-pulse.service pipewire-pulse.socket pipewire.service pipewire.socket` to refresh everything and get it running on Pipewire. I played around and these were the 4 important ones I found. This updated my list of devices in GNOME Settings and made everything start working. Replace restart with status to confirm everything is active and running.
> 6. Run `systemctl --user enable pipewire-pulse.service pipewire-pulse.socket pipewire.service pipewire.socket` (same as Step 5 but replace restart with enable). This should make sure everything starts back up again after a reboot. I haven't tried rebooting my whole machine yet but I don't forsee any issues.

In my case, steps 1, 3, 4, 5 (in that order) were enough to get back audio to normal.

I didn't have to reboot or logout, it worked on the spot, I checked by testing multiple videos and audio files, stopping and resuming. Even videos in browsers are working again, this problem caused playback problems leading to them not starting, nor playing.

However, I did reboot to check, and this solution seems to hold.